# Represent nested parameters for Neo4j query in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I tried to run Neo4j queries with parameters in the form of the Map[String, Anyref] which works just fine. However, I would like to send the data to Neo4j in form of the batch so the result would be Map[String, Map[String,AnyRef]] or Map[String, AnyRef] if the data is converted. But overall I would like to set the data in such a way:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": 193331567,
      "lat": 40.7599983215332,
      "lon": -73.98999786376953
    },
    {
      "id": 173062762,
      "lat": 41.959999084472656,
      "lon": -87.66000366210938
    },
    {
      "id": 66276172,
      "lat": 40.72999954223633,
      "lon": -74.01000213623047
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote it in Scala using nested maps, however, when I pass this nested maps as a parameter to the query it cannot be rendered by Neo4j. So how can I represent this nested JSON structure in Scala? Should I use and Object instead or something like that?

Here is the map I set up:

```
val paramsList = Map("nodes" -> {
    data map { seq =>
      Map(
        "lat" -> seq(1).toDouble.asInstanceOf[AnyRef],
        "lon" -> seq(2).toDouble.asInstanceOf[AnyRef],
        "id" -> seq(0).toInt.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
      )
    }}.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])

val queryResults = neo4jSession.run(neo4jQuery, params.asJava)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was important to convert both maps to java.util.Map so Neo4j would be able to pass this data as a parameter.

```
val paramsList = data map { seq =>
          Map(
            "lat" -> seq(1).toDouble.asInstanceOf[AnyRef],
            "lon" -> seq(2).toDouble.asInstanceOf[AnyRef],
            "id" -> seq(0).toInt.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
          ).asJava.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
        }
    val queryResults = neo4jSession.run(neo4jQueries.searchQueryWithBatchParams, Map("nodes" -> paramsList.asJava.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]).asJava)
```